# How to add packages to .Net Core console app when they do not resolve?

Tags: visual-studio-code, .net-core, command-line-interface

I am working through a tutorial on .Net core apps and Visual Studio Code, and cannot add a package to the app.

Using the CLI I did:

```
dotnet new console

dotnet run
```

Which worked fine.

Then I run:

```
dotnet add package System.Net.Http
```

And got this result:

```
$ dotnet add package System.Net.Http
  Writing C:\Users\xxx\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpF935.tmp
info : Adding PackageReference for package 'System.Net.Http' into project 'C:\Visual Studio Code\learning-module\learning-module.csproj'.
log  : Restoring packages for C:\Visual Studio Code\learning-module\learning-module.csproj...
error: Unable to resolve 'System.Net.Http ' for '.NETCoreApp,Version=v2.2'.
error: Package 'System.Net.Http' is incompatible with 'all' frameworks in project 'C:\Visual Studio Code\learning-module\learning-module.csproj'.
```

I've tried manually adding the package to the project file and running restore; changing the target framework; running from the console rather than Visual Studio Code; and trying different common packages, but nothing seems to resolve.

```
$ dotnet --info
.NET Core SDK (reflecting any global.json):
 Version:   2.2.103
 Commit:    8edbc2570a

Runtime Environment:
 OS Name:     Windows
 OS Version:  10.0.14393
 OS Platform: Windows
 RID:         win10-x64
 Base Path:   C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\2.2.103\

Host (useful for support):
  Version: 2.2.1
  Commit:  878dd11e62

.NET Core SDKs installed:
  2.1.503 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]
  2.2.103 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]

.NET Core runtimes installed:
  Microsoft.AspNetCore.All 2.1.7 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.All]
  Microsoft.AspNetCore.All 2.2.1 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.All]
  Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 2.1.7 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
  Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 2.2.1 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
  Microsoft.NETCore.App 2.1.7 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]
  Microsoft.NETCore.App 2.2.1 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]

To install additional .NET Core runtimes or SDKs:
  https://aka.ms/dotnet-download
```

Does anyone know what else I could try or how to find out more info on this issue?

Answer (score 2):

System.Net.Http is a standard namespace in .Net Core 2. You shouldn't need to add an external package.

Just put a using statement at the top of your code:

`using System.Net.Http;`